# What is the number of trees? tagged trees

Tags: graph-theory, trees

**Question**: what is the number of trees T(V,E) on the set $({v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5,v_6,v_7,v_8})$ that have at least **two** vertices with a 3 degree.

edit: would like if someone can confirm I did it right:

total number of trees: $8^6 - \frac{8!}{2} - \frac{6!}{2} * 8 * 7 = 221824 $

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By rank do you mean degree (the number of adjacent vertices)? Also, do you mean at least two vertices with degree *at least* 3? (As in your example, which has a degree 3 and degree 4 vertex.)

Comment: @Misha yes editing sorry. there can't be a vertex which has a 4 degree there are not enough vertices for that

Comment: Your example does have a vertex with degree 4: the rightmost vertex in the second layer has a parent and three children.

Comment: Oh you're right

Comment: Does a "tree" mean a rooted or unrooted tree for you?

Comment: @HenningMakholm unrooted

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the high-degree vertices have degree **at least** $3$, there are several possible pictures (not just this one). I think it's easier to do complementary counting. [Cayley's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_formula) tells us that there are $8^6$ labeled trees total, so all we need to do is find the number of labeled trees with at most one high-degree vertex, and subtract it from $8^6$.

(This helps not just because there's fewer cases, but because the cases are simpler.)

If no vertex has degree more than $2$, then we have a path. There are $\frac{8!}{2}$ ways to label the vertices (dividing by $2$ to account for the fact that we can look at the path from two ends).

If there is only one vertex of high degree, the graph we get is called a "spider", because graph theorists are weird. There's a central vertex, and several paths radiating out from it. The total length of the paths is $7$, so we have several cases to consider, but each of them is fairly simple: for example, if we have a path of length $3$ and four paths of length $1$, we can label the vertices in $8!$ ways, but the four paths of length $1$ are identical and can be rearranged in $4!$ ways, for $\frac{8!}{4!}$ distinct labelings.

You have some casework to do for the spiders, but this should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. one last thing: the final answer is 6720? as the other guy mentioned?(I'm asking to check myself)

Comment: 6720 is the number of ways to label the tree in your example above; there are other trees of different shapes. I get 20160 labelings of the path, and 139784 labelings of the different spiders, for a final answer of $8^6-20160-139784 = 102200$.

Comment: Ok i'll come up with an answer and i'd like if u can confirm(editing my question with an answer

Comment: edited my question please take a look

Comment: @user21312 That's substantially too few spiders. You have to consider all the possible path lengths: $5+1+1$, $4+2+1$, $4+1+1+1$, and so on. The only good thing is that each individual case is easy to handle; the only symmetry that a spider has is permuting "legs" of the same length.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a number of other shapes of tree that meet your requirement.  I don't know an easy of finding them.  You just need to carefully draw them.  For the tree you show there are only three equivalent vertices-the leaves coming off the four vertex.  The other two leaves are distinguishable by their positions in the tree, so the number of ways to label it is $\frac {8!}{3!}=6720$